# Windows 2008 SSL Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, ssl, encryption

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine hosting sites from IIS 7.
I have bought certs from trusted authorities before and installed on IIS 6, but I just want to make my own certificate to encrypt the data, and I am not sure how to go about doing this on server 2008.

How can I use Server 2008 to generate an SSL Certificate to secure a site?

How then do I install the certificate on a site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good guide on self signed certs the MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/archive/2009/01/23/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way.aspx. Just remember users will still be prompted that your cert isn't valid since it is self signed so it is not trusted by the users computer.

Comment: Correct about the prompt UNLESS he deploys it as a trusted cert ahead of time using group policy.